# iOS English numbers are automatically getting changed to Arabic despite Apple Language code is set to en in UserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Currently I am facing weird issue with localization stuff. Whenever I type English numerals, they get changed to Arabic even when Apple Language is set to en in UserDefaults.

```swift
if langCode == ENGLISH_CODE {
    defaults.set(["en","ar"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    defaults.set(true, forKey: IS_LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)}
else {
    defaults.set(["ar","en"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    defaults.set(false, forKey: IS_LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)
}
```

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: May be some texfield delegate is changing them?

Comment: I am not explicitly changing characters. Even this issue is appearing in the read only views.

Comment: May be you have some libraries that do it automatically? Can you reproduce it on clean project?